# App Termination Event WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am developing a WP8.1 app in which I need to get the time when app terminated so that when it's launched again I can take decisions according to my requirements. But for this I'm unable to find the any kind of termination event for app where I can store the time of app termination. I have searched and have found [Windows Phone 8.1 App Life Cycle](http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/40) which shows there is no event for termination. So my question is how can I record the time of app termination?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the suspension time? When the actual process goes away may have nothing to do with when the user stopped using the app or when any code you wrote last ran.

Comment: I tried but it was causing error which was due to my code. I managed to resolve it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the suspension of the application, when it is brought to the background, and record that time. It is the time when the user last used your app, so when it is started again, you can check how much time has elapsed since last use.

For the actual termination you do not receive an event, nor it is a way to handle such event, because all processing in the application is stopped when suspended and no code can execute.

Comment: I looked a lot and finally this is the option I can go for because it is closest to my problem. Thanks for your answer.